# help with rosrun image_transport

Tags: rosrun, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/ExaminingImagePublisherSubscriber
But when i ran rosrun image_transport my_publisher path/to/some/image.jpg it says

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named my_publisher below /opt/ros/indigo/share/image_transport
```

i think there is a mistake in http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages where after git clone it says
mkdir src which is already there.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200091/help-with-rosrun-image_transport/) by [neoDEH](https://answers.ros.org/users/20383/neodeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image_transport is a different ROS package. Your project is named image_transport_tutorial and you simply need to launch

> rosrun image_transport_tutorial my_publisher
> path/to/some/image.jpg

in order for it to work. You have to make sure that your project is in ROS working path.

---

Originally posted by [Alexandre.Willame](https://answers.ros.org/users/21108/alexandre.willame/) with karma: 46 on 2015-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1